# Can't send email in management command run by cron

Tags: django

I have a strange problem with a Django management command I am running via cron.

I've a production server set up to use Mailgun. I've a management command that simply sends an email:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Send email'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        send_mail('Test email', 'Test content', 'noreply@example.com', ['me@example.com',], fail_silently=False)
```

This script works perfectly if I run it via the command line (I'm using virtualenvwrapper):

```
> workon myapp
> python manage.py do_command
```

or directly:

```
> /home/user/.venvs/project/bin/python /home/user/project/manage.py do_command
```

But when I set it up with cron (`crontab -e`):

```
*/1 * * * * /home/user/.venvs/project/bin/python /home/user/project/manage.py do_command
```

The script *runs* (without error), but the email isn't sent.

What could be going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, the issue was that the wrong `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` env var was set and there were a few things throwing me off the scent:

My `manage.py` script defaults to the "development" version of my settings: `settings.local` and this uses the command line email backend. Cron suppresses all output so I wasn't seeing that happening.

Secondly, I was testing in a shell that already has `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` set to `settings.production`, so it appeared that the script ran correctly when I ran it on the command line.

The fix is easy, add `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` to the crontab:

```
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=config.settings.production
*/1 * * * * ...
```